# Android 5.1 full phone encryption stuck 12+ hours in

Tags: 5.1-lollipop, disk-encryption

Similar thread to [this](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/126523/214713) one.
None of the answers were helpful.

- It's an unrooted Android 5.1.
  The device has been factory reset.
- Once I begin the encryption process, screen is stuck with displaying bare android logo:
  [image: bare android logo, with no progress bar, no text, no nothing]

  Seen pictures on the internet with some progress indication, which is missing in my case, so something must be up:
  [image]
- The phone does not overheat, so the encryption clearly hasn't begun.
- I'm able to cancel the process by holding power button for 10s.
  Once rebooted, the system is untouched, just as it was before the encryption attempt.
- Retried the process with `$ adb logcat` active on USB.
  Nothing suspicious in [the logs](https://www.dropbox.com/s/cgh22agem6me329/log.txt?dl=0), although I don't know what to look for too.

  **Meta:** *Will delete the link with logs and paste only relevant lines once there's a working solution.*